# Towards safer chemotherapy: What is the current state of cancer therapy using targeted drug-delivery?

Tags: cancer, treatment, chemotherapy

I work in the biophysics of making non-viral drug-delivery vectors, which can encapsulate the drug molecules and release the drugs at targeted sites.

The release mechanism at targeted sites are generally governed different techniques like

- pH sensitivity (it is known that cancerous cells are slightly more acidic) [1]
- hyperthermia-induced drug delivery (local heating of tumour cells, to allow release only in that region) [2]

I wanted to know what is the current status of availability of such treatment protocols in the medical industry? Have they become scalable with ability to reach the patients? Further, will these options make chemotherapy much more safer than they are currently?

[1] Xi He, Jianfeng Li, Sai An, and Chen Jiang, pH-sensitive drug-delivery systems for tumor targeting, *Therapeutic Delivery* 4(12), 1499-1510, (**2013**)

[2] Hynynen, K. Hyperthermia-induced drug delivery in humans. *Nat Biomed Eng* 2, 637–639 (**2018**)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. If you work in this industry, you probably know more than many of us do (I don't think we have any oncologists on this site.) Protocols are country-dependant, and yes, many chemotherapeutic agents are much safer, more specific, and more effective today as inroads are made in Molecular Biology, Genetics, and Immunology. While cancer diagnoses are on the rise (for many reasons), so are cure rates for many of them.

Comment: I don't work in the industry. I work at a research institute where we do some basic science research which are aimed at screening the components of drug-delivery vectors at a very primitive level. We don't currently collaborate with industries. I Just wanted to know what is the status in the medicine community about such therapeutics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.